# wysiwyg edior giving error on image upload

Tags: admin-panel, wysiwyg, magento-1.5.1

I am New with the Magento and I am facing some problem when I try to upload Image through wysiwyg editor in admin panel then image is not uploaded and when 
I press save button following error message appears

```
error: error in [unknown object].fireEvent():

event name: formSubmit

error message: tinyMCE.get is not a function
```

so please help me in this problem

Comment: Do you have the option to get to a newer version of magento than 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

1.5.1 is fairly old, your going to want to grab a newer version if possible.

There are several old threads refering to issues with tinymce, dated appropriately for your version. You may need to dig into this some more, and find out why its not able to call tinyMCE.get().

Please respond with your ability to upgrade.