# Unable to upload product image in magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9

Get an error message when trying to add product image

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUHAk.png

Comment: Check file permissions on media folder (775 for directory and 664 for files)

Comment: set  permissions on media folder.. but still getting the same error :(

Comment: 1.) Did it work before? 2.) What did you change before it stopped working? Please update your question with some more information.

Comment: i have changed permission on media folder.. then upload image to a product.. but its getting the same error[see screenshot]

Comment: plz help me to solve this issue.. :(

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/sandermangel/beforeYouPostHereDidYouTry-magento1, especially the basic debugging steps. With only this information posted there, there can be too much reasons. Update your questions with your findings from debugging.

Comment: which php version you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wysiwyg edior giving error on image upload](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55697/wysiwyg-edior-giving-error-on-image-upload)

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered in the same issue when I installed magento with php 7 during the analysis I came to know the issue was coming through below file ;

> E:\Xampp7\htdocs\magento19\lib\Varien\File\Uploader.php:274
>   Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in

To resolve this issue just replace below code:

```
At Line 274: $params['object']->$params['method']($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

to

```
$params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Open file : /public_html/lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

Find: (line: 272)

//run validate callbacks

```
foreach ($this->_validateCallbacks as $params) {
            if (is_object($params['object']) && method_exists($params['object'], $params['method'])) {
                $params['object']->$params['method']($this->_file['tmp_name']);

            }
        }
```

And Replace:

//run validate callbacks

```
foreach ($this->_validateCallbacks as $params) {
            if (is_object($params['object']) && method_exists($params['object'], $params['method'])) {
                $params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
            }
        }
```